# Delete file used by another process and get its info

Tags: c#, process, pinvoke

I'm writing a program that searches for some files and deletes them. I desire to implement two things (probably using PInvoke):
- find all the processes that use "found file", kill it and delete file,
- get info about that process (its name should be fine - for log).
Do you know any useful PInvoke methods?
Thx in advance.

Comment: A google search reveals a Raymond Chen article about finding processes that have a file open:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/17/10268840.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

- [Processes and Thread Functions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [File Management Functions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

*Specifically, the functions that will likely come in handy are:*

- [MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [NtQueryInformationProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) now replaced by [GetProcessInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also, bear in mind that you need a good C++ knowledge when developing a program to operate on files and processes. I learnt this the hard way while I was developing an anti-malware tool.